# Set path for ValidationMessages.properties in SPRING

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I configured messages.properties to be accesible from the folder locale/ setting this parameter in application.properties:

```
spring.messages.basename=locale/messages
```

This works fine. Now, I also have the file validationMessages.properties but it has to be in the root path to be accesible. I've tried using a comma in the parameter:

```
spring.messages.basename=locale/messages,locale/validationMessages
```

But this doesn't work. I'm configuring the app using beans, not the XML but I cannot find a way to set this correctly.

Comment: Did you try `spring.messages.basename=locale`?

Comment: Something I don't uderstand..... I supposed that locale/messages means that the file is going to be called messages.properties, message_ES.properties etc that Is why I added locale/validationMessages

Comment: Is locale folder on your classpath?

Comment: Yes.. That is working for messages.properties. I just wanted to add validationMessages.properties to the locale folder

Answer (score 0):

This spring.messages.basename property is supposed to store locations of various localized 'message.properties' files, i.e. directory names, not the particular file names.
So in your case, you just have to put your validationMessages.properties to local/messages directory, and it should work.

You can figure out how it works here
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1e8b9569d3a3900a0ed61712099823ad735b8078/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L185